# The meaning of this 痛い

Tags: translation

> また首負傷しためっちゃ痛い.

What does this 痛い mean? It sounds like someone is in pain physically? Can it be emotional?

Comment: What is your understanding of this sentence? Unfortunately this question looks like a translation request which this website does not accept.

Comment: I've learnt japanese for 2 months only with RTK and Genki. The kanji i recognise are the one for wound, pain and I understand nouns like めっちゃ. So I just thought it would mean like "I'm in a lot of pain." But due to pain having multiple interpretations in English, it leads me to my question. Sorry

Comment: So... [また](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F), [首](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%A6%96) and [負傷](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%B2%A0%E5%82%B7)

Answer (score 6):

If this is the full context, this 痛い simply refers to the physical pain the speaker is feeling in the neck. You don't have to overthink about it for now.

> また首(を)負傷した。めっちゃ痛い。
>   <sub>(Punctuation added for clarity)</sub>
>
> (I) injured my neck again. (I'm) terribly in pain.

If you explicitly say 心が痛い, it can refer to a psychological pain, too, although we usually simply say [つらい](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%BE%9B%E3%81%84-1) for this sense.

In addition, 痛い on its own has several abstract and slangy meanings:

1. (situation) "bad", "tough", "inconvenient", "unfortunate"
2. (personality or phrase) "cringe-worthy", "pathetic", "try-hard"

But I think these are irrelevant in your case.